# Length of maximum continuous subarray with 2 unique numbers

Tags: algorithm, vector, data-structures

I have an array of numbers and I want to figure out the maximum length of a continuous subarray of 2 unique numbers repeating.

For example, [2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4] would return 3 since [3, 2, 2] is of length 3.

```
[2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 2] would return 3.
[7, 8, 7, 8, 7] would return 5.
```

Edit: I have considered an O(n^2) solution where I start at each value in the array and iterate until I see a third unique value.

```
for item in array:
    iterate until third unique element
    if length of this iteration is greater than existing max, update the max length
return maxlength
```

I do not, however, think this is an efficient solution.

Comment: What have you tried? You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you post a partial solution, rather than ask for someone else to to write an entire solution for you.

Comment: What does `maximum length of 2 numbers repeating until I see a third unique number` mean, how did you get 5  and 3 in the examples below, please clarify?

Comment: I have added the method I have tried. I got 5 since there were only 2 unique elements in that array so I could iterate through the entire array (of size 5). I want to find the length of the maximum subarray of 2 unique elements. I got 3 in the prior array since [2, 4, 2] or [5, 1, 5] are both of length 3.

Comment: I have just renamed the question to more appropriately reflect the problem at hand

Comment: Shouldn't 3,4,3 return 3 in the first example?

Comment: @Surt Doesn't matter what subarray returns the value, since maximum is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done O(n). The code is in python3. `o` and `t` are one and two respectively. `m` is the max and `c` is the current count variable.

```
a = [7, 8, 7, 8, 7]
m = -1
o = a[0]
t = a[1]
# in the beginning one and two are the first 2 numbers 
c = 0
index = 0
for i in a:
    if i == o or i == t:
        # if current element is either one or two current count is increased
        c += 1
    else:
        # if current element is neither one nor two then they are updated accordingly and max is updated
        o = a[index - 1]
        t = a[index]
        m = max(m, c)
        c = 2
    index += 1
m = max(m, c)

print(m)
```

Comment: What’s is the complexity of a.index()?

Comment: It is O(n), my bad. But since I was using index of the current element and not searching in the whole array it is not necessary  and can be used using index variable in O(1).

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Try to use`a = [2, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7]`. Solution is wrong.

Comment: fixed, needed to update m after exiting the loop, thanks for feedbacks

Comment: Looks valid, but could you add an explanation, line-comments, or more-than-one-letter variables?

Comment: done, this is some what like the other answer by nightfury1204, where one and two have similar purpose of 2 pointers.

Comment: This still fails. Check with `a = [1,1,1,1,1]` or `a = [1,1,1,1,2]`.

Comment: @gc7 also for `[1,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: @vivek_23 the output is 5 for `a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` which is correct I guess

Comment: @gc7 it should be `0` since there is only 1 unique element. OP wants it with 2 unique numbers and not at most 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182789/discussion-between-gc7-and-vivek-23).

Comment: Not working. For [1, 1, 2] answer is 3 but your code returns 2.

Answer (score 0):

We can use two pointer technique to solve this problem in O(n) run time complexity. These two pointer for example `startPtr` and `endPtr` will represent the range in the array. We will maintain this range `[startPtr, endPtr]` in such way that it contains no more than 2 unique number. We can do this by keeping track of position of the 2 unique number. My implement in C++ is given below:

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,1,3,4};
    int startPtr = 0;
    int endPtr = 0;

    // denotes the size of the array
    int size= sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

    // contain last position of unique number 1 in the range [startPtr, endPtr] 
    int uniqueNumPos1 = -1; // -1 value represents it is not set yet

    // contain last position of unique number 2 in the range [startPtr, endPtr]
    int uniqueNumPos2 = -1; // -1 value represents it is not set yet


    // contains length of maximum continuous subarray with 2 unique numbers
    int ans = 0;

    while(endPtr < size) {
        if(uniqueNumPos1 == -1 || array[endPtr] == array[uniqueNumPos1]) {
            uniqueNumPos1 = endPtr;
        }
        else {
            if(uniqueNumPos2 == -1 || array[endPtr] == array[uniqueNumPos2]) {
                uniqueNumPos2 = endPtr;
            }
            else {
                // for this new third unique number update startPtr with min(uniqueNumPos1, uniqueNumPos2) + 1
                // to ensure [startPtr, endPtr] does not contain more that two unique
                startPtr = min(uniqueNumPos1, uniqueNumPos2) + 1;

                // update uniqueNumPos1 and uniqueNumPos2
                uniqueNumPos1 = endPtr -1;
                uniqueNumPos2 = endPtr;
            }
        }

        // this conditon is to ensure the range contain exactly two unique number
        // if you are looking for the range containing less than or equal to two unique number, then you can omit this condition
        if (uniqueNumPos1 != -1 && uniqueNumPos2 !=-1) {
            ans = max( ans, endPtr - startPtr + 1);
        }

        endPtr++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", ans);
}
```

Thanks **@MBo** for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: `int array[] = { 1,2,3,3,4,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,1,3,4 };` gives answer 9.

Comment: Thanks @MBo for pointing out the mistake. I forgot to consider repetition of unique number 1 when updating `uniqueNumPos1`. Now i updated my ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.lang.System.out;
class TestCase{
    int[] test;
    int answer;
    TestCase(int[] test,int answer){
        this.test = test;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCase[] tests = {
                            new TestCase(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4},3),
                            new TestCase(new int[]{2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4},7),
                            new TestCase(new int[]{1,2,3,3,4,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,1,3,4},7),
                            new TestCase(new int[]{2, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7},5),          
                            new TestCase(new int[]{-1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,-1,-1,4},13),
                            new TestCase(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7},3),
                            new TestCase(new int[]{0,0,0,0,0},0),
                            new TestCase(new int[]{0,0,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},7),
                            new TestCase(new int[]{},0)
        };

        for(int i=0;i<tests.length;++i){
            int ans = maxContiguousArrayWith2UniqueElements(tests[i].test);
            out.println(Arrays.toString(tests[i].test));
            out.println("Expected: " + tests[i].answer);
            out.println("Returned: " + ans);
            out.println("Result: " + (tests[i].answer == ans ? "ok" : "not ok"));
            out.println();
        }         
    }

    private static int maxContiguousArrayWith2UniqueElements(int[] A){
        if(A == null || A.length <= 1) return 0;
        int max_subarray = 0;
        int first_number = A[0],second_number = A[0];
        int start_index = 0,same_element_run_length = 1;
        for(int i=1;i<A.length;++i){
            if(A[i] != A[i-1]){ 
                if(first_number == second_number){
                    second_number = A[i];
                }else{
                    if(A[i] != first_number && A[i] != second_number){
                        max_subarray = Math.max(max_subarray,i - start_index); 
                        start_index = i - same_element_run_length;
                        first_number  = A[i-1];
                        second_number = A[i];
                    }
                }
                same_element_run_length = 1;
            }else{
                same_element_run_length++;
            }
        }

        return first_number == second_number ? max_subarray : Math.max(max_subarray,A.length - start_index);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4]
Expected: 3
Returned: 3
Result: ok

[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4]
Expected: 7
Returned: 7
Result: ok

[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4]
Expected: 7
Returned: 7
Result: ok

[2, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7]
Expected: 5
Returned: 5
Result: ok

[-1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, 4]
Expected: 13
Returned: 13
Result: ok

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]
Expected: 3
Returned: 3
Result: ok

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Expected: 0
Returned: 0
Result: ok

[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Expected: 7
Returned: 7
Result: ok

[]
Expected: 0
Returned: 0
Result: ok
```

**Algorithm:**

- So, we maintain 2 variables **first_number** and **second_number** which will hold those 2 unique numbers.
- As you know, there could be many possible subarrays we have to consider to get the max subarray length which has 2 unique elements. Hence, we need a pointer variable which will point to start of a subarray. In this, that pointer is **start_index**.
- Any subarray breaks when we find a **third** number which is not equal to **first_number** or **second_number**. So, now, we calculate the previous subarray length(which had those 2 unique elements) by doing **i - start_index**.
- Tricky part of this question is how to get the **start_index** of the next subarray.
- If you closely observe, **second_number** of previous subarray becomes **first_number** of current subarray and **third** number we encountered just now becomes **second_number** of this current subarray.
- So, one way to calculate when this **first_number** started is to run a while loop backwards to get that **start_index**. But that would make the algorithm **O(n^2)** if there are many subarrays to consider(which it will be).
- Hence, we maintain a variable called **same_element_run_length** which just keeps track of the length or frequency of how many times the number got repeated and gets updated whenever it breaks. So, **start_index** for the **next subarray** after we encounter the **third** number becomes **start_index = i - same_element_run_length**.
- Rest of the computation done is self-explanatory.
- Time Complexity: **O(n)**, Space Complexity : **O(1)**.

Comment: I'm really curious as to how the heck `[-1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, 4]` comes out to 13. (Admittedly, I'm trying to NOT read your post as I'm still working on this algorithm, but -1 and 2 are > 2 numbers apart, are they not?)

Comment: @ScottFraley Old post, didn't read through my answer completely but `[-1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1]` is the window of size 13 as the answer. -1 and 2 are the 2 unique numbers in the window. They need not be consecutive in nature.

Comment: Oh, interesting. As I've seen this problem described, the numbers are supposed to be "consecutive in nature." Here's the description I started with; 

Longest Subarray 

Given an array of integers, what is the length of the longest subarray `containing no more than two distinct values such that the distinct values differ by no more than 1?`

Comment: @ScottFraley It doesn't say that anywhere in the question.